# Existence of pairs

Tags: real-analysis, periodic-functions

Let $p,p_1,p_2$ be positive integers such that $lmc(p_1,p_2)=p$. Is $\min(p_1+p_2)$ unique?

Comment: Just a quick thought since no one has replied: Is this maybe equivalent to just asking whether, given an integer $p$, that among all $(p_1,p_2)$ for which $LCM(p_1,p_2)=p$, there is always a unique pair $(p_1,p_2)$ for which $p_1+p_2$ is the minimum possible (wlog assuming $p_1\le p_2$)? My quick guess is that this is true. I’m not sure how anything about the periodic functions makes things more complicated here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $p_1, p_2$ are two integers such that $\text{lcm}(p_1, p_2)=p$, the only way that $p_1+p_2$ could be minimum is if $p_1$ and $p_2$ had no common factors. If they had a common factor $q$ with $q$ being a prime, then either $p_1$ or $p_2$ could be divided by $q$ and $\text{lcm}(p_1, p_2)$ would still equal $p$, while $p_1+p_2$ would be smaller. So $\gcd(p_1, p_2)$ must equal $1$. Together with $\text{lcm}(p_1, p_2)=p$, that implies $p_1p_2=p$.

Now it remains to show that if $p_1\le p_2$ and $q_1\le q_2$ are integers such that $p_1p_2=p=q_1q_2$ and $p_1+p_2=q_1+q_2$, then $p_1=q_1, p_2=q_2$ (you don't even need the fact that $\gcd(p_1,p_2)=1=\gcd(q_1,q_2)$). This follows from the fact that $p_1p_2=p$ and $p_1+p_2=n$ completely constrains what $p_1$ and $p_2$ can be. The only solution would be $p_1=\frac{n-\sqrt{n^2-4p}}{2}, p_2=\frac{n+\sqrt{n^2-4p}}{2}$.

Intuitively, you can think of this as meaning that if $p_1p_2=p$ and $p_1\le p_2$, then decreasing $p_1$ would increase $p_2$ more than $p_1$ decreases.

Comment: You have a firm grasp on it. Thanks.

Comment: @CelineHarumi $p_1$ seems to correspond to https://oeis.org/A052128, $p_2$ seems to correspond to https://oeis.org/A354933, and $p_2−p_1$ seems to correspond to https://oeis.org/A076388.